# There is no "less" filter

Tags: node.js, installation, less, orocrm

I'm installing orocrm and I receive the error in the title.
The error is raised by the subcommand assetic:dump called by oro:install command.
I installed node.js and less. I've seen that in app/config/config.yml there is

```
 # Assetic Configuration
 assetic:
     debug:                    false
     use_controller:           false
     filters:
         cssrewrite: ~
         lessphp:
             file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/leafo/lessphp/lessc.inc.php
             apply_to: "\.less$"
         cssmin:
             file: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/php/cssmin-v3.0.1.php
```

I don't understand what is missing, please help me.

Comment: What version do you install, can you describe what you did, and provide please some info about your environment. Thanks

Comment: you install `node` and `less` but try to use lessphp?

Answer (score 1):

For the Node.js version of less try sometng like that shown below:

```
assetic:
    filters:
        less:
            node: /usr/bin/node
            node_paths: [/opt/lessc/lib, /usr/lib/node_modules]
            apply_to: "\.less$"
```